# What is the logical consequence of a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know that the logical consequence of a contradiction is the whole Language $\mathcal{L}$ : $Cn(\bot) = \mathcal{L}$, but what is the logical consequence of a tautology is it $Cn(\top)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical consequence of a tautology must be a tautology.

If $A$ is a tautology, it means that $A$ is true in every interpretation, i.e. every interpretation is a *model* of $A$.

But $A \vDash B$, we have that $B$ must be true in every model of $A$, and thus also $B$ is true in every interpretation.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for your answer!